# How can I pass a variable in a foreach loop using links

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I am attempting to make a website that will load a certain menu.xml doc, that was sent to it using a foreach loop. The foreach loop uses glob to grab all XML docs in a directory then prints the "name" attribute into a html link.

This has worked to up until the point were I need to pass the certain XML var used to make the link to another php doc that utilizes it.

I first attempted to use the $_SESSION to but could not as the loop would overwrite $_SESSION with each iteration. I also tried $_GET and $_POST, but I ran into the same problem with forms.

Here is my code (Please ignore any sloppyness, I am new to the PHP game):

```
foreach(glob("../menus/*xml") as $dom) //grabs each .xml doc in menus/
{
    $menu = simplexml_load_file($dom); //loads the file into $menu
    print "<li>";
    print "<a href = menu.php>{$menu["name"]}</a>"; //links to page menu.php
    print "</li>";
}
```

What I need this to do now, is to pass the individually loaded XML variable when the link is clicked.

How could I go about doing this?

Edit:

menu.xml is a page that displays the contents of the menu.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
foreach(glob("../menus/*xml") as $dom) //grabs each .xml doc in menus/
{
  $menu = simplexml_load_file($dom); //loads the file into $menu
?>
<li>
    <a href="menu.php?name=<?php echo $menu["name"] ?>><?php echo $menu["name"] ?></a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

The variable will be set into `$_GET['name']` when the page is loaded.

Comment: This method looks like it would work, except that the 'name' var has a space, and so the page won't take it.

Comment: This one worked quite well, I just needed to create an ID tag in the place of "Name" because the "name" attribute has a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the DOMs in an associative array:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($dom);
$arr_item = array($xml["name"] => $xml);
$menu[] = $arr_item;
```

create the form line:

```
print "<a href = menu.php id='{$xml["name"]}' name='{$xml["name"]}' >{$xml["name"]}</a>";
```

and then when you want to call it, you can use its name to get the `$dom`:

```
$dom_obj = $menu["name"];
```

Comment: This seems like it will work. I'll try it out and get back to you.